# Property 'containerComponent' is missing in type '{}'

Tags: reactjs, devexpress, paging

I'm using react to render HTML and I'm using `PagingPanel Plugin` from react-grid.
However when I add this rule:

```
import { PagingPanel } from '@devexpress/dx-react-grid';
```

And in my `render()` I add this rule:

```
<PagingPanel />
```

It gives me the following error:

```
Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'PagingPanelProps'.
Property 'containerComponent' is missing in type '{}'.
```

What am I missing?
I'm using `PagingPanel` inside the `grid` component also from `react-grid`

My code inside the `render` method:

```
<Grid rows={this.props.ConnectedConnectors}
 columns={[{ name: "guid", title: "Guid" }]}>
 <SortingState sorting={this.props.sorting} onSortingChange={this.props.changeSorting} />
 <SearchState value={this.props.searchValue} onValueChange={this.props.changeSearchValue} />
 <IntegratedFiltering />
 <IntegratedSorting />
 <PagingState pageSize={10} currentPage={this.props.pageNumber} onCurrentPageChange={this.props.changePageNumber} />
 <IntegratedPaging />
 <Table cellComponent={this.renderCell.bind(this)} columnExtensions={this.tableColumnExtensions} tableComponent={TableComponent} />
 <Toolbar />
 <SearchPanel />
 <TableHeaderRow showSortingControls />
 <TableColumnVisibility hiddenColumnNames={hiddenColumnNames} emptyMessageComponent={NoGridColumnsMessage} />
 <PagingPanel />  // the one with the error mark
 <SelectionState  />
 <TableSelection selectByRowClick highlightRow showSelectionColumn={false} key="id" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the documentation on this component [here](https://devexpress.github.io/devextreme-reactive/react/grid/docs/reference/paging-panel/)

You will want to use a `PagingPanel` from one of the theme components if you are not providing a custom component.

Excerpt:

```
// Use the following statement to import a plugin with embedded theme components:

import { PagingPanel } from '@devexpress/dx-react-grid-material-ui';
import { PagingPanel } from '@devexpress/dx-react-grid-bootstrap4';
import { PagingPanel } from '@devexpress/dx-react-grid-bootstrap3';

// If you want to use custom components, you can import the themeless plugin:

import { PagingPanel } from '@devexpress/dx-react-grid';
```